# How to find a basis consisting of eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2 =$
>    $T$. Discuss whether or not there exists a basis of $V$ consisting of
>   eigenvectors of $T$.

The answer in the back of the book says:

> The minimal polynomial of $T$ divides $x^2 - x$, and therefore has distinct linear factors in $C[x]$. There does exist a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors.

Please explain to me the process of arriving at this conclusion. Thanks!

Comment: The question doesn't ask you to _find_ an eigenbasis, just whether there _exists_ one under the assumption that $T$ is idempotent. **Hint:** Consider putting $T$ on Jordan normal form.

Comment: The identity transformation satisfies this, and for it there does exist such a basis. So your claim that you "already know that there does not exist such a basis" is not correct.

Comment: Thank you both for your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a linear operator $T \,:\, V \to V$ with  $T^2 = T$.

Let $U$ be the *range* of $T$. Obviously, $T|_U = \textrm{id}_U$, i.e. $T$ acts as the identity on $U$, otherwise we wouldn't have $T^2 = T$.

Let $W$ be the *kernel* of $T$, i.e. $W = \textrm{ker } T = \{v \in V \,:\, Tv = 0\}$. We have $U \cap W = \{0\}$, because if $x \in U$ then $Tx = x$ (by the above), so $Tx = 0$ only if $x = 0$, meaning $x \notin W$ unless $x = 0$.

For linear operators from a vector space to itself we always have that $$
  \dim \underbrace{\textrm{ker } T}_{=W} + \dim \underbrace{\textrm{rng }T}_{=U} = \dim V \text{.}
$$
Since $U \cap W = \{0\}$, it follows that $$
  V = U \oplus W \text{.}
$$

But now we're done. We simply pick a basis $b_1,\ldots,b_k$ of $U$, append a basis $b_{k+1},\ldots,b_n$ of $W$, then $$
  T b_i = \begin{cases}
    b_i &\text{if $b_i \in U$, i.e. if $1 \leq i \leq k$} \\
    0   &\text{if $b_i \in W$, i.e. if $k < i \leq n$.}
  \end{cases}
$$
Obviously, all the $b_i$ are thus eigenvectors of $T$, the first $k$ having eigenvalue $1$ and the others eigenvalue $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is a projection and it's diagonalizable since the polynomial with simple roots $x^2-x$ annihilates $T$. Ah $T$ is diagonalizable means that we can find a basis of vectors in which $T$ is diagonal so what we can say about those vectors?