# Types of idempotent matrices $A^2 = A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Types of idempotent matrices $A^2 = A$

Can I classify some types of matrices as idempotent ?

The trivial examples are $0$ and $I_n$, and I've also found that a matrix with one row all equal to $1$ and every other row equal to $0$ is idempotent.

Comment: A small search on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix) turns up some info. Also, a very similar question has been asked [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42283/constructing-idempotent-matrices) on this site, containing some hints.

Comment: What are their eigenvalues?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x(x-1)$, if $A\neq I_n$ and $A$ isn't the null matrix. Therefore $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: You could classify them into those with determinant one and those with determinant zero.

Comment: Hi Daniel, so those with determinant one satisfy $A^2 = A$ ? why ?

Comment: Not all matrices with determinant one satisfy $A^2 = A$.  But since $\det(A)\det(B) = \det(AB)$, then zero and one are the only possible determinants.

Comment: @user111854, He never said that, he's just saying you could classify them into 2 categories. It's a one way implication

Comment: Ahh, but could I find a group that does satisfy $A^2 = A$ ?

Comment: @user111854 What do you want exactly?

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774692/how-to-find-a-basis-consisting-of-eigenvectors) question and it's answers.

Comment: @GitGud : I want to know whether there exists a class of matrices like diagonal, upper triangular or whatever that satisfies $A^2 = A$.

Comment: My [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775511/types-of-idempotent-matrices-a2-a#comment1609213_775511) implies that such matrices are similar to matrices that look like $\begin{bmatrix} I & \large 0\\ \large 0 & \large 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: How can you every get a characteristic polynomial on that form ? The degree must be at least $n$ ?

Comment: @user111854 The degree of the characteristic polynomial is exactly $n$, yes. I didn't understand your question.

Comment: You refer to a minimal polynomial, which has degree $2$ ? What is a minimal polynomial ?

Answer (score 1):

Such matrices are projection operators on $\mathbb{F}^n$, and are always diagonalizable. The matrix $A$ is then similar to Dg$[I_r,0]$ where $r$ is the rank of $A$, that is, you can find an invertible matrix $P$ so that $P^{-1}AP=$ Dg$[I_r,0]$.

In this particular case we always have that $\mathbb{F}^n$ is the direct sum of the nullspace of $(A)$ and the column space of $A$, and we say that $A$ is the projection of $\mathbb{F}^n$ onto the column space of $A$ along the nullspace of $A$.

Furthermore if the column space of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the nullspace of $A$ then $A$ is an orthogonal projection, and you can find a unitary matrix $P$ so that $P^{*}AP=$ Dg$[I_r,0]$. So we can say if $A$ is not an orthogonal projection, it is an oblique projection.