# similarity class of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Over $\mathbb{C}$, what is the number of similarity classes of $n\times n$ idempotent matrices? Also how to find the number of similarity classes of  $n\times n$ matrices with a given characteristic or minimal polynomial? Is there any general formula?

Comment: Use the Jordan normal form.

Comment: ok is there any general formula??

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775511/types-of-idempotent-matrices-a2-a.